# Sudo svn to update as other user

Tags: linux, svn, sudo

I want our developers (including moi) to be able to run `svn update` as user www-data on our server, for file/directory permissions.

My solution was to grant access to run `sudo -u www-data svn` with NOPASSWD in visudo. I also added an alias for this command, and named it `svn` to make it transparent for our developers.

This works, but I am asked for *svn* credentials every time (it doesn't save, even if I tell it to). I am thinking about adding the `-i` parameter, though I thought I should check with you guys first :)

How do I make this as smooth as running the `svn update` command normally?

**Clarification:** It is working now. I just don't want to enter my svn credentials every time I run `svn update` :)

Comment: If you show your line in the sudoers file, we might see what's wrong. Perhaps you should include a full path to the svn binary in the sudoers file. (The sudoers file is what you edit with the visudo command)

Comment: From sudoers file: %admins ALL=(www-data) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/svn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not entirely sure, but passing `-H` as an argument to sudo might take care of the credentials issue (being asked each time).

This will set the HOME environment variable to /root by default, so I would *guess* that then the svn client my then know to look in /root/.subversion for the auth information.  Specify a different home directory for wherever the credentials should be for your specific case.  Also, make sure whatever use can write/read to that file.

Comment: `-H` will set `HOME` to default homedir of the user specified; since he's using it with `-u www-data` that'll probably be `/var/www` (i think that's default on ubuntu; check `/etc/passwd` to be sure).  otherwise this sounds reasonable.

Comment: This sounds like the solution I was looking for. I think the problem is that it is trying to store the SVN password in my home, and fails because it hasn't write access.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this what setuid was made for?  Create a script or compiled binary (depending on your security requirements) that does the update (one `system` call should do it), and have it setuid and owned by www-data.

Comment: umm... setuid on the `svn` binary??  only if that's the only user you ever want to use `svn` on that system.

Comment: No; write a short compiled program or script that does what you want (depending on security concerns) and run that setuid.

Comment: ah.  that makes sense; should edit your answer to include such details.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try running it with svn update --username wwwdata

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is implemented differently between different distros - which are you using?

For RHEL5:

```
    Cmnd_Alias      SVN = /usr/bin/svn
    herbert         ALL = NOPASSWD: SVN
```

Alternatively you can achieve the same thing with a single script (to restrict the user to a subset of the target program's functionality)

Comment: Ubuntu 9.x is my dist